# how to convert 8 byte array acquired from cfgmgr32.dll to datetime in delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I have an 8 byte value I got from cfgmgr32.dll which represents a install date of a device driver value, from its function CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW.

I have been trying to convert it to datetime but no success, at the moment I am lost.
(190, 100, 92, 19, 132, 46, 209, 1) is a value I got, this value represents a datetime value, I need a hint where to start to convert it.
any example or hint using c++ or Delphi pascal is welcome, Delphi is preferred.

Comment: Have you try declare variable of TDateTime tipe and then use `procedure CopyMemory(Destination: Pointer; Source: Pointer; Length: DWORD)` to copy data from your 8byte value to this var?

Comment: Can you show the code how you are calling the dll function? And a link to the ms docs. It seems as it is not a TDateTime value.

Comment: @LURD Since it's an MS DLL it makes sense that it's the native Win32 type

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, your assumption is most likely correct. The details should have been included in the question, though.

Comment: I reverted your edit because it was the easiest way for me to keep my answer matching your question. FWIW, the code in that now reverted edit doesn't work. You should: 1. remove the `datebuf` variable and 2. write `FileTime := PFileTime(_propBuf)^;`

Comment: I got a typecast error that's why i declared, fastly, a second byte array of 8 length. 
Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but your code then copied the pointer and not what it referred to.

Comment: coban, if you could try to make your question in the form of english sentence, instead of in the form of sentence fragments, it would make it easier for other people to read your questions.

Comment: I will do my best next time, sorry for bad english (sentence), this is maybe because of that english is not my main language. 
If everything should make sence (for me), the question should not make any sence :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know more information. What do those 8 bytes represent? I think the bytes represent a `FILETIME` value which would seem reasonable for data returned by a Win32 DLL.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

const
  Input: array [0..7] of Byte = (190, 100, 92, 19, 132, 46, 209, 1);

var
  FileTime: TFileTime;
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;

begin
  FileTime := TFileTime(Input);
  Win32Check(FileTimeToSystemTime(FileTime, SystemTime));
  Writeln(SystemTime.wYear);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wMonth);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wDayOfWeek);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wDay);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wHour);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wMinute);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wSecond);
  Writeln(SystemTime.wMilliseconds);
  Readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
2015
12
5
4
11
8
16
583
```

The device driver was installed on the 4<sup>th</sup> December 2015?

For future reference it would probably be more helpful if you had included more details in the question as to how you came about these 8 bytes.

According to information in the comments you are calling `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW`. In that case you should check the returned property type. I expect it to be [`DEVPROP_TYPE_FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543590.aspx). That documentation tells you the following:

> In Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, the
>   DEVPROP_TYPE_FILETIME property type represents the base-data-type
>   identifier that indicates that the data type is a FILETIME-typed
>   value.
>
> ....
>
> We recommend that all time values be represented in Coordinated
>   Universal Time (UTC) units.

Comment: Agree. There are just too many time/date formats (and offsets) around.

Comment: I used the external function "CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW" from cfgmgr32.dll
this function has 4 outputs, result of the call, value in byte array, value type and the count of the bytes.

the function is described at msdn.

Comment: Actually that is not correct. There are 4 outputs. The one that you are missing is the property type. My intuition tells me that it will be [`DEVPROP_TYPE_FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543590.aspx). This information should be added to the question really. But I suspect that we are done now.

Comment: Probably want to convert to localised time as the stamp seems to be in utc?
FileTimeToLocalFileTime -> FileTimeToSystemTime -> SystemTimeToDateTime

Comment: @Remko Left as exercise for reader. I just wanted to show that the value was a `FILETIME`.